# eclipse java content assisst doesn't work for particular class, work for other classes in project

Tags: java, eclipse, code-completion

I am stuck in strange error in my eclipse, in which content assist always shows empty when I press ctrl+space, in bottom it shows error "No completions available". This error is for a particular class, while content assist works well in other class.

My eclipse is helios under windows xp.

I have tried cleaning the project, removing and re inserting the file, tried to check all the values under preferences>java>editor>content assist>advanced but nothing works.

What should I do to prevent this error?

Comment: Have you built the project, or automatic build on?

Comment: automatic build on.... cleaned and built twice

Comment: That is rather difficult to answer without a look on the class in question. It is something you can send?

Comment: What should I send? Any log? If yes can you give more details?

Comment: Does your code have compile errors? Are you using Maven? You could try to move the file to another package and see if it works there.

Comment: No there is no maven in eclipse, and code is without any compile error.... and class can not be moved in other project. Should I install maven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the visibility of the class with which content assist does not work. If you are trying to call a method of that class, then check the visibility of that method as well. If you want that class/method to be accessible outside the package the you have to make that class/method `public` You can learn more about the visibility modifiers [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)